# Trait 'Illuminate\Support\Traits\MacroableTrait' not found

Tags: laravel

I Install Laravel and include the package [[https://github.com/jakubsacha/adminlte]](https://github.com/jakubsacha/adminlte%5d). Now I get the following error:

```
cartalyst/sentry suggests installing illuminate/database (Default sentry user, group and throttling implementations.)
cartalyst/sentry suggests installing ircmaxell/password-compat (Default hashing uses PHP 5.5 password_* functions, with forward-compatible support.)
cartalyst/sentry suggests installing happydemon/txt (Required Text helpers when using the Kohana implementation)
```

ERROR:

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error.

[RuntimeException]

Error Output: PHP Fatal error: Trait 'Illuminate\Support\Traits\MacroableTrait' not found in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 3228
```

Comment: Try `composer update --no-scripts` once then run again without the `--no-scripts` flag.

Comment: @Unnawut no change. When I run composer update --no-scripts it give no Error. Bur when again I run composer update it give same error.

Comment: Tried this http://laravel.io/forum/02-01-2014-updating-to-4119-artisan-clear-compiled-returned-with-an-error ?

Comment: @Unnawut When I change the script it give same error.

Comment: Have you tried deleting bootstrap/compiled.php ?

Comment: @Strixy yes I have tried deleting compiled.php but get same error. I change Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 4.1 . It give no error but now my Laravel Site stop working.